# GATE ontology editor with Arabic lang

Tags: gate

Dears, 
I use  Gate Developer 8.5, and Ontology plugin, Ontology Editor :
I load my initial file "test.owl", its classes' names were written  in Arabic Language,  but when I try to update this file , like adding sub class and try to write its name in Arabic,
I get an error: invalid class name, so, how can I enable Arabic characters in Ontology Editor interfaces.

adding sub class with English name done successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite surprised that class names can use Arabic characters directly.

According to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/1857897

nonstandard characters in URIs need to be encoded with the percent-encoding...

You should be able to use Arabic characters in class **labels** without problems. But I'm not sure about class names...